# Is there a more comprehensive JavaScript function reference than w3schools?

Tags: javascript, api, documentation

I've been searching around online for a while now and I can't seem to find any particularly impressive function references for JavaScript.

Of course, [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) and <del>[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)</del> have good information, but they're not as complete for JavaScript as the [flash component reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) and [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) are for flash and jQuery.

So does anyone know of a good JavaScript reference with some or all of the following qualities?

- Documentation on most functions/objects/packages/prototypes
- Browser compatibility
- examples of usage
- clean layout
- community comments/examples
- library APIs

Comment: Having *no* reference is probably better than using W3Schools

Comment: +1 @scunliffe, @Nick Craver, & @Sime Vidas thanks for the good references. I don't want to _not_ award an answer, but I'm not really sure who deserves it the most. I went with first response.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mozilla has very complete docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

DevGuru has a very complete list also

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/javascript_index.html

in addition if you want to see all the quirky differences that Microsoft implemented then MSDN provides a fairly complete (but not frequently updated or corrected) set of docs here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533054%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 17):

Yes, the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript) is a much better area, it lacks the community integration, but the descriptions and organization are *much* better (and more accurate) than w3schools.

Comment: Indeed - just yesterday I saw someone comment somewhere (can not find it!) that they just append "mdc" to their google queries on JavaScript reference questions to get the preferred mdc results first and foremost

Comment: @Matt - I didn't catch that...but I do the same :)

Comment: *it lacks the community integration* It's a wiki, so you the community can modify it :)

Answer (score 8):

For the built-in objects, the reference is in the ECMAScript spec:
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

For the host objects, use MDC and MSDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/gecko_dom_reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050(VS.85).aspx

Also, there is the Webkit DOM Reference (but it seems somewhat sloppy):
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/index.html

Then again there are the web-standards defined by W3C. You can use my W3 Viewer to browse them:
http://www.w3viewer.com

(The standards of interest are in the "JavaScript" and "DOM" categories)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, nothing beats the reference of the book [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000480).

Comment: I considered mentioning that I own that book.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript Kit have a pretty good one: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/

A little harder to digest, but perhaps more complete (but only including the core, not web-specific stuff like `window` or `document`) is the ECMAScript specification: http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php

And then there are the Mozilla and MSDN references, for browser specific stuff. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1et7k7c(VS.94).aspx