# Use &middot; instead of bullet for <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I found an article on the [list-style-type property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) in CSS, but it doesn't list the &middot; (·) as an option, as opposed to the default `disc` or &bullet; (•). Is there a way to do this with HTML or CSS?

Comment: obligatory [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) reference

Comment: doesn't mean they aren't useful for references

Comment: @stevo225, [I used to like w3schools once upon a time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159226/is-there-a-more-comprehensive-javascript-function-reference-than-w3schools), but then i discovered that reading the specifications was actually very easy and that w3schools is wrong too often for me to ever trust it. If I can't trust it as a source, it ceases to be useful in any meaningful way.

Comment: But why use the fools when the real [W3 references](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style) are so [much better](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-content)?

Comment: I understand completely, but with anything on the internet, I feel I must test it myself anyway, I am distrustful from the start. And since they do have a large set of references, I don't mind starting there.

Comment: @steveo225, the specification is the document that **defines** how the language must work. For particular browser implementations you can use [quirksmode's compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) as an accurate reference.

Comment: Also, you can [ban sites from your search results](https://www.google.com/reviews/t), as I have done to w3schools. I have found the quality of my results has drastically improved and I can find accurate information much faster.

Comment: For all the whiners against w3fools - novices don't read the specs because they are daunting and too comprehensive for most daily needs. Instead, point them to *user-friendly docs* such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com), or even... I was going to recommend [Apple Dev Club](https://developer.apple.com), but stick to the former two. Also [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/).

Comment: I hate w3schools, but I hate w3fools even more. Why not provide a *specific* article (perhaps on MDN) that does a better job, rather than pointing to that useless webpage over and over?

Comment: On the topic: The interpunkt (aka ”middot”) is typographically used to separate words. I haven't heard about any language where the interpunct is actually used in lists or similar. That explains why it's not a standard option.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

CSS (works in any browser supporting `:before` and `content:` ):

```
li:before { 
    content: '\b7\a0'; /* \b7 is a middot, \a0 is a space */
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    text-indent:-.5em; /* helps make it look more like it's a bullet. */
}
```

**Caution:** It is not a real list style.  Therefore, when you have wrapped lists, it will look funny. This can perhaps be mitigated by a negative text-indent of a few units to get it to function more like a list-style.

---

Another implementation:

```
li:before {
    content: '\b7\a0';
    position:absolute;
    right:100%
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}
```

This version seems to work better.  I often use `:before` and `:after` to add extra things like borders, but if you are adding a bullet I imagine that that is not the case.  Even though this is the alternate suggestion, it is probably the preferred one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!  You can use the `before` pseudo-class to insert the character before each item.

```
.DotList li:before
{
    content: "·";
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/m8FvU/) is an example jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

[`list-style-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type) doesn't select what character to use, it selects an abstract marker to use. Note the standard states:

> The value 'none' specifies no marker, otherwise there are three types of marker: glyphs, numbering systems, and alphabetic systems.
>
> Glyphs are specified with disc, circle, and square. Their exact rendering depends on the user agent.

For more control over the marker, you must either set an image using [`list-style-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image) or use the [`:before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after) pseudo element and [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) property, setting the `list-style-type` to 'none'. `:before` and the [`content` property](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter_content.html) aren't supported in IE 7 and earlier, so you must either use `list-style-image` to support IE 7 or simply let IE 7 use a different marker. You can use conditional comments to target IE 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an background-image in LI

One possible example
http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical05.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are a limited number of available options for `list-style-type` which are defined in the [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#list-style).

You can use:

- disc
- circle
- square
- decimal
- decimal-leading-zero
- lower-roman
- upper-roman
- lower-greek
- lower-latin
- upper-latin
- armenian
- georgian
- lower-alpha
- upper-alpha
- none

If you'd like something custom, use [the `list-style-image` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image)

If you're styling for browsers that support generated content, you can use:

```
li:before {
  content: '\[utf-8 hex code for character]';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will lead to strange behaviour if your list text is pushed out of position by a floating element. The bullets will not be shifted even though the text will, and the result will probably be undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `li:before`, which affects all li's (in menu, tabs, accordion) on page, I have used this:

```css
ul {
 list-style: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAHCAMAAAAYuxziAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAABhQTFRF////cmpmZmZm+MGYqNP/Zmt/06N6j7j/ImXnGgAAABpJREFUeNpiYAABZkZWFgY2JiZ2CAsVAAQYAAPiACwnaqqBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
}
```

```html
  
<ul>
  <li>This is my middot</li>
</ul>
```