# Add array to two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Array A is a two dimensional array. It's made up of array X and Y. I'd like to add array Z to Array A as another item in Array A. How do I do this?

**Edited** to add code:

```
arrayA = new Array(
    [1, 2, 3] //array x
    [4, 5, 6] //array y
    );

arrayZ = new Array(7, 8, 9);

//now, how do I add arrayZ onto the end of arrayA?
```

Comment: read the [faq]. post the code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will add it to the end of arrayA

```
arrayA.push(arrayZ);
```

Here's a reference for `push`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: [Use MDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159226/is-there-a-more-comprehensive-javascript-function-reference-than-w3schools)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, lots of responses as to how to add items to arrays, but lets start with making your code better:

```
arrayA = [ //don't use new Array()
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

arrayZ = [7,8,9];
```

There're a few ways you can do this.

You can use the array methods [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) or [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
arrayA.unshift(arrayZ) //adds z to the front of arrayA
arrayA.push(arrayZ) //adds z to the end of arrayA
```

You can also set the location explicitly:

```
arrayA[0] = arrayZ //overwrites the first element
arrayA[1] = arrayZ //overwrites the second element
arrayA[2] = arrayZ //adds a new element at 2
arrayA[arrayA.length] = arrayZ //essentially the same as using push
```

You can also [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the new element into the array:

```
arrayA.splice(1, 0, arrayZ)
```

`1` specifies the start index of the elements being inserted/removed .`0` specifies how many elements should be removed, in this case we're adding and not removing any. `arrayZ` is the element to insert

Answer (score 4):

You could push your arrays onto Array `a` like so

#### JavaScript

```
var a = new Array();
var x = new Array();
var y = new Array();
var z = new Array();

a.push(x);
a.push(y);
a.push(z);
```

**Edit:** After OP edited question with code example:

```
var z = new Array(7, 8, 9);
var a = new Array(
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
);

a.push(z);
```

Answer (score 3):

Without any code I am just assuming

arr[0] = is array X

arr[1] = is array Y

so you can use arr[2] for Y

```
var foo = new Array()
foo[0] = new Array() // Your x
foo[1] = new Array() // Your y
foo[2] = new Array() // Your z
```

Answer (score 2):

On *ES6* you can use the spread operator (`...`) as follows:

```
arrayA = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]
];

arrayB = [7,8,9];

arrayA = [...arrayA, ...[arrayB]];
```