# javascript date to string() doesn't work for me, not even on w3schools example

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying basic toString on the javascript date object, and after it wasn't working I went to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp and the two examples they give show the same values!!

Original form: Thu Dec 01 2011 12:15:52 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
To string: Thu Dec 01 2011 12:15:52 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

Comment: obligatory [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) reference.

Comment: What was the code you wrote? What was the expected result? What was the result you got? I don't think anyone can tell you what the problem without some more information.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Maybe you could post your code that doesn't work and describe the problem?

Comment: Sorry guys! Here's my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/QwzUK/ I'm getting the same result for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w3schools is [not a good JavaScript reference](http://w3fools.com/). It has numerous issues and should not be trusted.

[one of my first questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159226/is-there-a-more-comprehensive-javascript-function-reference-than-w3schools) was about where to find a comprehensive JavaScript reference.

The Mozilla Development Network has a more accurate reference for the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: @LeviMorrison, to which version of my answer were you replying?

Comment: Your original.  Deleted the comment.  Will delete this one shortly.

Answer (score 2):

The example you linked to is meant to show that when you try to use a Date object in a context that expects a String, Javascript will automatically call its toString() method. You are meant to get the same value twice.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: This method is automatically called by JavaScript whenever a
>   Date object needs to be displayed as a string.

So `d+''` is the same as `d.toString()`.